# Showing that $ U(2^n) $ is not a cyclic group for $ n \geq 3 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Could anyone please explain to me why $ U(2^n) $ is not a cyclic group for $ n \geq 3 $? I need help on this because I have an algebra exam tomorrow. Thanks!